# How do I detect battery accurate battery level? Separate framework?

Tags: ios, frameworks, battery

I am trying to make an app that detects the battery percentage of the device.

However I only get my battery percentage in multiples of 5 from this following code:

```
float batteryLevel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel];

batteryLevel *= 100;

labelPercentage.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", batteryLevel];
```

How do I display it in multiples of 1, what would be a separate framework that I may use?

Comment: @JustinJohns Nup does not work!

Comment: Without jailbreaking, 5% is as precise as you get. See the linked duplicate answer for discussion of getting 1% accuracy after jailbreaking, alternative method doing image processing on the status bar battery meter etc.